# Configure SSL certificate by ACM on single instance tomcat on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, single-instance

I have created a single instance web application on AWS with Elastic Beanstalk. Now I want to add ssl certificate to enable https access on it.

I created a ssl certificate using ACM and I was folowing [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html)! link to add it to my web app in Elastic Beanstalk.

But I could not find  and   anywhere in acm.

How can i find them??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use ACM with CloudFront or Elastic Load Balancers. Since you don't have an Elastic Load Balancer in a single instance Elastic Beanstalk environment, you can't use ACM, unless you want to put CloudFront in front of it.